# How to set cookies to a website by using file_get_html

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get some pricing information from a website. The website will prompt a window to select country. After selecting a country, the website will set a cookie and will show the data according to that country.

I used `file_get_html` to parse data from the website. The problem is, It showing default price. So, My question is, Is it possible to set cookie as per we want using the `file_get_html` or any other way to do it.

The code I am using to parse data from the website are the following.

```
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$content = "http://www.luluwebstore.com/products/lulu-household-pets-pet-food/purina/purina-dog-chow-little-bites-dry-food-181-kg/pid-8263178.aspx";
$html = file_get_html($content);
echo $price = $html->find('div[class=price_stockdiv_l3]',0);
```

The result of the above code is:

> OUR PRICE : AED 10.00 MRP : AED 11.00
>   9%off

By default, the website will fetch **AED** pricing, but, I want the result in **QAR** pricing. If we are browsing the website first time it will promot a window to select country.

The site following a cookie like the below to save the country.
[image]

Comment: try "[curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)"

Comment: How to use Curl to set cookie?

Comment: take a look to this  [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872082/how-can-i-send-cookies-using-php-curl-in-addition-to-curlopt-cookiefile) - [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028258/sending-cookies-stored-on-cookie-global-using-php-curl) - and if you need any explanation code tell me and i will post answer

Comment: I am still having the same problem. I can't set the cookie. Please give me the answer with code that set location id to as follows in the image.